# How To Dynamically Build Grid-Area-Templates of (n x n) Grid Using SASS function

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

I have hardcoded the following CSS `grid-area-templates` for a `5x5` grid:

```
  #grid {
    grid-template-areas:
      "0-0 0-1 0-2 0-3 0-4"
      "1-0 1-1 1-2 1-3 1-4"
      "2-0 2-1 2-2 2-3 2-4"
      "3-0 3-1 3-2 3-3 3-4"
      "4-0 4-1 4-2 4-3 4-4"
  }
```

However I want grids of multiple sizes and i'd like to dynamically build them. Because of this, I'd like to write a function that will take in `j` and `i` such that:

```
@function buildGrd(j,i) {
  @return // [snip]
}

// @buildGrid(5,5) =>
"0-0 0-1 0-2 0-3 0-4"
"1-0 1-1 1-2 1-3 1-4"
"2-0 2-1 2-2 2-3 2-4"
"3-0 3-1 3-2 3-3 3-4"
"4-0 4-1 4-2 4-3 4-4"

#grid-small {
  grid-template-areas: @buildGrid(5,5)
}

#grid-large {
  grid-template-areas: @buildGrid(25,25)
}
```

I've tried using `@for` and `@mixin` variations but struggled to do this so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can generate your grids:

```
@function buildGrid($j, $i) {
    $template: null;
    
    @for $x from 0 to $j {
        $string: '';
        
        @for $y from 0 to $i {
            @if $y > 0 { $string: $string + ' '; }
            $string: $string + $x + "-" + $y;
        }
        
        $template: $template $string;
    }
    
  @return $template;
}

#grid-small {
  grid-template-areas: buildGrid(5,5);
}

#grid-large {
  grid-template-areas: buildGrid(25,25);
}
```

However, it will generate the template on a single line as:

```
#grid-small {
  grid-template-areas: "0-0 0-1 0-2 0-3 0-4" "1-0 1-1 1-2 1-3 1-4" "2-0 2-1 2-2 2-3 2-4" [...];
}
```

As far as I know, this code is still valid though. I'm not sure it's possible to generate multiple strings on multiple lines with SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do it like this also

```
@function buildGrid($j, $i) {
    $result: "";
    @for $cur from $j - $i to $j {
        $result2: "";

        @for $current from $j - $i to $j {
            @if($result2 == "") {
                $result2: #{$cur}-#{$current};
            } @else {
                $result2: append($result2, #{$cur}-#{$current});
            }
        }

        @if($result == "") {
            $result: "#{$result2}";
        } @else {
            $result: append($result, "#{$result2}");
        }
    }
    @return $result;
}

#grid-small {
    grid-template-areas: buildGrid(5, 5)
}

#grid-large {
  grid-template-areas: buildGrid(25,25);
}
```